# Older version iOS simulators, like 6 or 5 with XCode 5.1 and OS X 10.9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

When I writing this question these are the latest XCode and OS X versions, just updated yesterday.

I can not believe that the only iOS version is 7.1 I can test my application against with the simulator... Or Apple suppose that all the mobile device owners have this latest iOS, and I as a developer targeting these users should share this crazy idea?

I must missed something, please point it out.

Almost forget: Where is the home button? See attached picture.

[image]

Comment: you can download iOS 6.1 simulator via Xcode -> Preferences. Otherwise keep older versions on your Mac instead of overwriting. note that all new uploads to the app store have to be done using Xcode 5 and SDK iOS7 .....

Comment: View the simulator at 100% size to see the Home button.

Comment: Some of the answers is helpful for you? Then why you don't accept one and vote up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To download older versions**:

Xcode / Preferences... / Downloads / You can download older Simulator versions from there

However,you are right, in Xcode 5.1 the only 2 older versions available are 7.0 and 6.1 if you are running Maverick.

**Home Button**: Shift + cmd + H

Comment: if youre on Elcapitan & xcode 7, be sure to open xcode using the terminal, or you get a weird authorization issue attempting to download older versions.
sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Answer (score 1):

iOS 5 simulator is not compatible with Mac OS X 10.9.2 (Maverick), so unless you have older machine with older OS, you're out of luck.

Other simulators you can download via Xcode Preferences - Downloads area. There's 6.1 and 7.0 currently.

Home button in simulator is shift-command-H (check the simulator menubar)